Bedrock server can't connect by DNS hostname, All other possible scenarios work
I have am running a new Bedrock server, latest version.  Everything seems to work fine.
I have both correct ports forwarded and TCP/UDP for both.
I can connect from Bedrock clients over the internet by WAN IPv4 address, and by WAN IPv6 address.
I have dynamic DNS set up (for quite some time) and the hostname works for everything else.
When I "Add Server" in the Bedrock client, and use that WAN hostname (either port for IPv4 or IPv6), Bedrock client is "Unable to connect to world."
I've been trying everything I can think of (I have good but older networking experience), and have been unable to figure it out.  Unfortunately Bedrock (both client and server) do not give much debug/troubleshooting feedback.
I can ping my dyn-WAN hostname, and it returns the correct IP v4 and v6 addresses, the same ones that work if used in Add Server.
I am also running a longstanding Minecraft Java server on a different machine.  We connect to it using the same dyn-WAN hostname, but totally different ports (numbers aren't even close), and that has always worked fine.
Searching all the usual places hasn't turned up any issues/advice about Bedrock and server hostnames.
My best guesses (which I have no practical way to verify) are:

Bedrock simply doesn't work right when given host/domain names and glitches out somehow.
(I can't find any pure Bedrock server hostnames to test online, they're all Java/Geyser crossplay.)
???

UPDATE:  I did find some information that Bedrock server requires a CNAME DNS entry for clients to be able to connect by hostname, for some reason.  I'm still trying after adding a CNAME record to my dynamic DNS host.  Perhaps this is the actual issue, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.  I can nslookup my new CNAME record (it's been up for a few names) but my Bedrock clients are still not connecting, so I don't know yet.

Hi Johnny, have you checked the list of existing questions (for example the ones that mention your error code)?

@Joachim I'm, not sure how to find a more specific error code, the "Unable to connect to world" is a generic error that could mean almost anything; although nearly infinite questions have that error I haven't found any that address the DNS-hostname issue that I'm facing here.

I have seen this on super user. It might be worth debugging if the issue is around having both servers running at the same time if they're not on sub domains.
